# Estimating the probability a measurement is between certain limits from variation, mean and number of measurements

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

I would like to estimate the probability that a measured value is between two limits, for example, it's below 50 or above 100, from an estimate of the variability in the measurement technique (σSD), the mean measured value (µ) and the number of measurements (N).  The distribution of the measured values are Gaussian, and I thought there would be a way to integrate the function 
[image]

between limits, for example, from -infinity to 50.  A little bit of digging showed I couldn't do this, and led me to the cumulative distribution function, and series expansion by integration by parts and I quickly got out of my depth and realised this isn't straight forward.  If it is possible to achieve this estimate, is there a formula for it, something that could be coded up (like a series expansion, for example)?

Comment: The cumulative distribution function for a Gaussian is also known as the error function, and is already provided in practically every scientific software stack. There should just be a built-in function for you somewhere. If you tell me what you're using, I may be able to help further.

Comment: Functions are implemented in many packages and in function libraries for many languages. These use approximate formulas that are highly accurate but they're complicated and typically come with many numerical constants that have to be accurately typed, and often with edge cases to deal with. The opportunities for mistakes are many -- frankly, unless there's some extremely compelling reason to do so, it's dumb to implement from scratch something that's already been implemented, debugged and very carefully tested and used for a long time (even subtle errors show). What are you trying to do it in?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments - I really appreciate it - and I've found the pnorm function in R which seems to do exactly what I want.

Comment: Yep. Such functions (or ones from which that can be easily computed) are in any stats package worth the name, and many packages for doing calculations (including Excel, by the way), as well as many numerical libraries.